# struts2 if tag compare javascript value with iterator variable

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

My bean class(User.java) looks like :

```
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userName;
    private String userPhone;

    //getters and setters
}
```

my struts2 action is:

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<User> users;
    // getUsers and setUsers method

    public String getUser() {

        //get all users
    }
}
```

the struts action getUser() will lead user to user.jsp and in this jsp page, client needs choose a user name from a drop down list, then this jsp page will set this user's email and phone in another input box.

this jsp(contains div and javascript) like next :

```
<div>
    .........   
   <tr>
       <td >User Name:</td>
       <td>
          <select id="authorizer">
               <option value=""></option>
               <s:iterator value="users">
                <option value="${userId}"><s:property value="userName" /></option>
                        </s:iterator>
                    </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td >User Information :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="contactInfo" /></td>
           </tr>            
    ......
</div>

<script>    

    jQuery( "#authorizer" ).change(function() {         

        if(jQuery( "#authorizer" ).val() != "") {           

            <s:iterator value="users">

                <s:if test="jQuery( "#authorizer" ).val() == userId">

                    jQuery("#contactInfo").val("${userEmail} ${userPhone}"); 
                </s:if>
            </s:iterator>
        }

  });

</script>
```

in my `<s:if test="jQuery( "#authorizer" ).val() == userId">`, I want to compare user id which client choose from page with struts iterator variable, but this  failed.

So how should I write the  such that I can compare the javascript value which user select on page with the iterator variable?

Comment: The value of the `test` attribute should be a valid OGNL expression, otherwise it won't evaluate.

Comment: @Roman C, then how can I reach my goal : when user select one user name from drop down list, then set its corresponding email and mobile in another input box in client side? or do I have to use ajax to get email and mobile in server side then set the value in client side?

Comment: It looks as though you're uncertain about which code is evaluated on the server, and which code is evaluated on the client. Java (servlets, actions, filters, JSP tags, JSP EL, etc.) is executed on the server *before the HTML is sent to the client*. JavaScript is evaluated on the *client* (e.g., browser). I'd take a step back and get that nailed down before going much further.